# Fast, simple assignment of flow directions to flats in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, flow, depression-filling

I have some enormously huge DEMs which I'd like to assign flow directions to. These DEMs are guaranteed to have no sinks, just flat areas.

It seems as though the only ways of assign flow directions to flats in GRASS involve doing depression filling (e.g. `r.terraflow` and `r.watershed` and `r.fill.dir`). In some cases, the fill is implicit, as in `r.terraflow`.

I'm looking for a simple, `O(n)` assignment of flow directions, similar to that presented by [Barnes et al. (2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S009830041300023X). Does GRASS include such a functionality?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "huge"? How many cols and rows approximately? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[r.watershed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.watershed.html) doesn't require filling depressions, because it uses least cost path for routing. Try -b flag (Flow direction in flat areas is modified to look prettier).

Comment: Unfortunately, least-cost paths reduce the algorithm to an `O(n log n)` running time and, based on the speed, the `n` is the entirety of the DEM. This operation's far too slow to be useful to me :-(

Comment: r.watershed is pretty fast, see for example http://www.hydrol-earth-syst-sci.net/15/667/2011/hess-15-667-2011.pdf.  Please accept my answer or reformulate your question.

Comment: The least cost path implicitly fills depressions. From the paper you provide: "If a depression is encountered, the search follows the steepest downhill slope to the bottom of a depression and then proceeds again along the least steep uphill slope." The Metz et al. algorithm has since been improved by [Barnes et al. (2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300413001337) (~37% improvement over Metz) and [Zhou et al. (2016)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300416300553) (44.6% improvement over Barnes). I've edited my question.

Comment: great chatting with you yesterday! I'd forgotten this particular question, but it's true: this answer didn't work for me. I ended up using a virtual tile approach and have ideas about how to do it faster. I'll be in touch about it.